# PUT request in my route not working as desired

Tags: javascript, express, postman

I am new to express.js and having issues updating one of my customers in the customers array (which is used as "database") using a PUT request in one of my routes. See my app.js below:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.json());

// Body parser
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// cors middleware
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

//const apiRouter = require('./routes/api');
//app.use('/api', apiRouter);

// get all customers
app.get('/api/customers', (req, res) => {
    res.send(customers);
})
const customers = [
    {
        name: 'John',
        id: 1,
        age: 30
    },
    {
        name: 'Mark',
        id: 2,
        age: 10
    },
    {
        name: 'Andrew',
        id: 3,
        age: 60
    }
]

/// get a customer by id 
app.get('/api/customers/:id', (req, res) => {
    const found = customers.some(customer => customer.id === parseInt(req.params.id));

    if (found) {
        res.json(customers.filter(customer => customer.id === parseInt(req.params.id)))
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({ msg: `No customers found with id ${req.params.id}` })
    }
})

// update a  customer 
// look up the customer, if not found return 404, else update the customer and return the updated customer
app.put('/api/customers/:id', (req, res) => {

    const customer = customers.find(c => c.id === parseInt(req.params.id));
    if (!customer) {
        res.status(404).res.send(`The customer with id ${req.params.id} was not found`);
    } else {
        customer.name = req.body.name;
        customer.age = req.body.age;
        res.send(customer);
    }

})


app.listen(PORT, (error) => {
    if (!error) {
        console.log("Server is Successfully Running and App is listening on port" + PORT)
    }
    else {
        console.log("Error occurred, server can't start", error);
    }
});

module.exports = app;
```

I am using postman and trying to retrieve the updated customer amongst the existing ones but it only creates a new one with his id but name and age are not showing up even if specified in the "body" option on Postman. I know it might be something silly but got stuck for a while. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you sending via the put request? Seems you might be sending an empty object, and therefore overwriting name & age with undefined. Try logging the `req.body` before assignment.

Comment: I am using postman and sending the below: {
    "name":"Simone",
     "age":"50"
}

Comment: Can you try copying it as a curl request? Just so i can see headers etc

Answer (score 0):

**wrong**:  res.status(404).**res**.send(`The customer with id ${req.params.id} was not found`);

**Right**:     res.status(404).send(`The customer with id ${req.params.id} was not found`);

Answer (score 0):

when your are using post man it must return json object

watch my change

```
res.status(404).json(`The customer with id ${req.params.id} was not found`);
```

Answer (score -1):

Make an update on routes controller. Try this on comment on now what are you seeing

```
app.put('/api/customers/:id', async (req, res) => {

    const customer = await customers.findById(req.params.id);
    if (customer) {
         customer.name = req.body.name;
          customer.age = req.body.age;

const updatedCustomer = await cutomer.save()
res.json(updatedCustomer );
        
    } else {
        res.status(404).res.send(`The customer with id ${req.params.id} was not found`);
    }

})
```

Comment: Did you got your result

Comment: There is no need to await or save here, as its just a plain array.

Comment: It is still not updating neither the name nor the age, it only creates a new ID

Comment: @SimoneGhilotti what you are getting as an result please tell

Comment: it is only updating my id but not the name or the age whenever I try and sent a put request on postman